# JavaScript - Compute height of an nary tree faster using array or linked list

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list, tree, breadth-first-search

I am not able to make my code run faster on longer inputs i.e. on taller or broader trees. It fails on trees of height around 1000.
**Can anyone suggest any edits to my code or any other algorithms to make this code run faster?**

**Question** - You are given a description of a rooted tree. Your task is to compute and output its height. Recall
that the height of a (rooted) tree is the maximum depth of a node, or the maximum distance from a
leaf to the root. You are given an arbitrary tree, not necessarily a binary tree.

**Input Format.** The first line contains the number of nodes . The second line contains  integer numbers
from −1 to  − 1 — parents of nodes. If the -th one of them (0 ≤  ≤  − 1) is −1, node  is the root,
otherwise it’s 0-based index of the parent of -th node. It is guaranteed that there is exactly one root.
It is guaranteed that the input represents a tree.

**Constraints.** 1 ≤  ≤ 105

**Output Format.** Output the height of the tree.

**Sample 1.**
Input:
5
4 -1 4 1 1

Output:
3

**Code** using linked list approach and BFS traversal -

```
var readline = require('readline');
var input = [];

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', function (cmd) {
    input.push(cmd);
});

rl.on('close', function (cmd) {
    input=input[1].split(" ");

    let tree1=list_to_tree(input);
    console.log( height(tree1));
    process.exit(0);
});

function list_to_tree(list) 
{
    var map = [], node, roots = [], i;
    for(i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    {
        map.push([{[i] :list[i],
            children:[]
        }]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    {
        node=map[i];
        if(list[i]!==-1 && list[i]!=="-1")
        {
            map[list[i]][0]["children"].push(node);
        }
        else {roots.push(node);}
    }

    return roots[0];
}

function height(tree)
{ 
    let h=0;
    if (tree===null)return;
    let  q=[];
    q.push(tree);
    while(q.length>0)
    {
        let l =q.length;
        while (l--)
        {
            let node=q.shift();
            q.push(...node[0]["children"]);
        }
        h++;
    }

    return h;
}
```

**Code** using array approach -

```
var readline = require('readline');

var input = [];

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', function (cmd) {
    input.push(cmd);
});

rl.on('close', function (cmd) {
   input=input[1].split(" ");

    let tree1=list_to_tree(input);
    console.log( height(tree1));
    process.exit(0);
});

function list_to_tree(list) {
    let map=[];roots=[];
    for (var x=0;x<list.length;x++){
        map[2*x]=x;
        map[2*x+1]=[];
    }
    for(var x=0;x<list.length;x++){
        node=map.slice(2*x,2*x+2);
        if(list[x]==-1){
            roots.push(...node);}
        else {
            map[2*list[x]+1].push(...node);
        }
    }

    return roots;
}

function height(tree) {
    if(tree==null){return 0;}
    let q=[];
    q.push(...tree);
    let h=0;
    while(q.length>0){
        let l=q.length/2;
        while(l--){
            q.shift();
            child=q.shift();
            q.push(...child);
        }
        h++;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So create an array of structures that have parent node number, and height. Initially, the heights will all be 0, except for the root, whose height you set to 1. Given your sample input, you have:

```
[
    {4, 0},
    {-1, 1},
    {4, 0},
    {1, 0},
    {1, 0}
}
```

Now, starting at the first item in the list, find its parent. If the parent's height is non-zero, then the node's height is one more than the parent's. Otherwise, find the parent's parent and see if its height is set, etc.

You use a stack to keep track of the nodes you've visited.

The algorithm looks something like this:

```
for each index, n
    while a[n].height == 0
        stack.push(n)
        n = a[n].parent
    parent = n;
    while !stack.isEmpty()
        stack.pop(n)
        a[n].height = a[parent].height + 1
        parent = n
```

At this point, all the nodes' heights have been set. You can scan the array to find the maximum height.

An obvious optimization is to keep track of the maximum height as you're scanning the tree. That is, after emptying the stack, you do this:

```
    if (a[n].height > max_height)
        max_height = a[n].height;
```

Given your input, we start at node 0. Its height is 0, so you push 0 onto the stack and look at node 4. Its height also is 0, so you look at node 1. Its height is 1, so you pop the stack, and assign node 4 the height value of 2. Then you pop the stack again and assign node 0 the height of 3. You end up with:

```
[
    {4, 3},
    {-1, 1},
    {4, 0},
    {1, 0},
    {1, 2}
}
```

Node 1 already has its height set. Node 2 has a height of 0, so you push it and look at node 4. Its height is 2, so you pop the stack and assign node 2 the height value of 3.

Node 3 has a height of 0, so you look at its parent, which has a height of 1. So node 3's height is 2. Finally, you look at node 4, whose height is already set. Your result is:

```
[
    {4, 3},
    {-1, 1},
    {4, 3},
    {1, 2},
    {1, 2}
}
```